# Highcharts.js - Event when any point is clicked

Tags: highcharts

There is an example here https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click/ of alerting when a marker on the series is clicked.

Is there any way to alert when any x,y point on the chart is clicked?

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the click event from the chart object.  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.click

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                var label = this.renderer.label(
                    'x: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].value, 2) + ', y: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.yAxis[0].value, 2),
                    event.xAxis[0].axis.toPixels(event.xAxis[0].value),
                    event.yAxis[0].axis.toPixels(event.yAxis[0].value)
                )
                    .attr({
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        padding: 10,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 8
                    })
                    .css({
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    })
                    .add();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    label.fadeOut();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/